# Spaces between non latin characters in plots in R

Tags: r

Additional spaces are always added at the beginning and end of strings with non-Latin characters.

Example with Cyrillic characters:

[image]

Latin characters:

[image]

The problem becomes more obvious in word clouds. For example:

```
library(Hmisc)
library(wordcloud)

letter <- "ж"
vec <- NULL
for(i in 3:25){
  string <- makeNstr(letter, i)
  vec <- c(rep(string, 25-i), vec)
}

wordcloud(vec, max.words=100, min.freq=1, scale=c(3, .1))
```

[image]

Result when `letter` is Latin:

[image]

If `vec` consists of non-Latin words, the wordcloud is less dense. Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: I saw this not only in ggplot.
Example for wordcloud:
library(wordcloud)
wordcloud(vec, max.words = 100, random.order = F)

If vec consists of non latin words, wordcloud will be less dense

Comment: Vector with strings like this :  "ярославль"       "краснодар"       "новороссийск"    "ростов-на-дону"  "сочи"            "барнаул"         "новокузнецк"    
 "кемерово"        "новосибирск"     "казань"          "нижний_новгород" "оренбург"        "самара"          "уфа"            
 "спб"             "москва"          "ангарск"         "брянск"          "владивосток"     "владикавказ"

Comment: I added completely reproducible example

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce this behavior on Ubuntu, with `Sys.getlocale()` set to `en_US.UTF-8`. What is your OS?

Comment: Windows.
Locale is `Russian_Russia.1251`